# Phalcon model is not recognizing AUTO_INCREMENT table column

Tags: php, mysql, model, phalcon

The current table Structure is:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title         | varchar(25)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| content       | varchar(500)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace Com\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness;

class Articles extends Model
{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $content;

    /**
     * Returns table name mapped in the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'articles';
    }

    /**
     * Allows to query a set of records that match the specified conditions
     *
     * @param mixed $parameters
     * @return Articles[]
     */
    public static function find($parameters = null)
    {
        return parent::find($parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Allows to query the first record that match the specified conditions
     *
     * @param mixed $parameters
     * @return Articles
     */
    public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
    {
        return parent::findFirst($parameters);
    }
```

Upon saving data from controller, I am receiving this error: `id is required`

**EDIT**

Here is the snippet for the save method:

```
$article = new Articles();

$article->title = $this->request->getPost('title', 'striptags');
$article->content = $this->request->getPost('content');

if (!$article->save()) {
    $this->flash->error($article->getMessages());
} else {
    $this->flash->success("Article created.");
    Tag::resetInput();
}
```

Comment: Updated the question with save method.

Comment: Do you have `modelsMetadata` service properly configured?

Comment: Yes, it is configured properly. The issue is with `Articles` model only.

Comment: do you fixed that issue?

Comment: @FazalRasel No, it was weird and I switched to NoSQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a problem with auto increment fields and Phalcon.
Only thing I can suggest is setting default to AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to give default value for a `primary key` column?

Comment: As an example you can add a primary key column 'id' and make it default auto_increment like:
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

This may help:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, that's how it is currently and it's not working for some weird reason. :(

Answer (score 0):

delete cache file

ex. "~\cache\metaData\meta-bds_models_yourmodel-your_model.php"